# Most efficient way to read huge local video file selected via file input

Tags: javascript, html, video

Code snippet below is a simplified example of an offline HTML video player I'm trying to develop.

The user is able to choose a video file, then this video file content is read into video player so user can play it.

**The problem here** is that the method I'm reading the video file with causes large memory leakage with large video files.

I'm using `readAsDataURL`, this is catastrophic in case of big files (e.g. for a ~200MB video file I get ~600MB webpage memory usage).

So, my question is, **what's the most efficient way to read a local video file selected by user into my HTML video player?**
I need a way that doesn't cause memory leakage like `readAsDataURL` does.

I think a direction to solution may be something that chunks local video files where only needed slices are loaded/unloaded to/from memory as needed like what happens with online videos. Also, a method that enables to read the video content directly from local hard disk instead of loading it to memory first as DataURL will be helpful.

Function responsible for passing selected video file as `src`:

```
function videoUpdateSource(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  reader.onloadend = function() {
    var videoTagElement_Exists = document.getElementById("loaded_video");
    !videoTagElement_Exists ? videoElementInitiate() : videoRemoveSources();
    videoAppendNewSource(reader.result);
  }
}
```

Full test snippet:

```js
function videoElementInitiate() {
  var videoElement = document.createElement('video');
  videoElement.setAttribute('id', 'loaded_video');
  videoElement.setAttribute('width', '480');
  videoElement.setAttribute('height', '300');
  videoElement.setAttribute('controls', '');

  document.getElementById("video_container").appendChild(videoElement);
  videoTag = document.getElementById('loaded_video');
}

function videoUpdateSource(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  reader.onloadend = function() {
    var videoTagElement_Exists = document.getElementById("loaded_video");
    !videoTagElement_Exists ? videoElementInitiate() : videoRemoveSources();
    videoAppendNewSource(reader.result);
  }
}

function videoRemoveSources() {
  videoTag.pause();
  var sourceElements = videoTag.getElementsByTagName('source');
  for (var i = sourceElements.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    sourceElements[i].remove();
  }
  videoTag.removeAttribute('src');
}

function videoAppendNewSource(src) {
  var source = document.createElement('source');
  source.setAttribute('src', src);
  videoTag.appendChild(source);
  videoTag.load();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Offline Video Player</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <p>Select Video file in order to play</p>
    <input type="file" id="fileElem" accept="video/*" onchange="videoUpdateSource(this.files[0])">
    <label class="button" for="fileElem">Select video file</label>
  </form>
  
  <br/>
  <div id='video_container'>
    <!-- loaded video element to be placed here -->
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Load as a blob, then use URL.createObjectURL? (On mobile, can't dig up there details.)

Comment: Amazing! this works as charm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx) ([comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64342837/most-efficient-way-to-read-huge-local-video-file-selected-via-file-input#comment113777774_64342837)) for suggesting a solution to use `URL.createObjectURL` instead of `readAsDataURL`.

Updating the function responsible for passing selected video file as `src`:

```
function videoUpdateSource(file) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);     // file is read as blob by default, check side note below.
  var videoTagElement_Exists = document.getElementById("loaded_video");
  !videoTagElement_Exists ? videoElementInitiate() : videoRemoveSources();
  videoAppendNewSource(url);
}
```

Side Note:

> A File object is a specific kind of a Blob, and can be used in any
> context that a Blob can. In particular, FileReader,
> URL.createObjectURL(), createImageBitmap(), and XMLHttpRequest.send()
> accept both Blobs and Files.
>
> [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

Now loading a 200MB or even 1GB video file results in ~60MB memory usage.

Updated code snippet:

```js
function videoElementInitiate() {
  var videoElement = document.createElement('video');
  videoElement.setAttribute('id', 'loaded_video');
  videoElement.setAttribute('width', '480');
  videoElement.setAttribute('height', '300');
  videoElement.setAttribute('controls', '');

  document.getElementById("video_container").appendChild(videoElement);
  videoTag = document.getElementById('loaded_video');
}

function videoUpdateSource(file) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file); // file is read as blob by default
  var videoTagElement_Exists = document.getElementById("loaded_video");
  !videoTagElement_Exists ? videoElementInitiate() : videoRemoveSources();
  videoAppendNewSource(url);
}

function videoRemoveSources() {
  videoTag.pause();
  var sourceElements = videoTag.getElementsByTagName('source');
  for (var i = sourceElements.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    sourceElements[i].remove();
  }
  videoTag.removeAttribute('src');
}

function videoAppendNewSource(src) {
  var source = document.createElement('source');
  source.setAttribute('src', src);
  videoTag.appendChild(source);
  videoTag.load();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Offline Video Player</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <p>Select Video file in order to play</p>
    <input type="file" id="fileElem" accept="video/*" onchange="videoUpdateSource(this.files[0])">
    <label class="button" for="fileElem">Select video file</label>
  </form>
  
  <br/>
  <div id='video_container'>
    <!-- loaded video element to be placed here -->
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```