# Wrong URI when trying to embed local audio file on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I drag and drop flac files into the browser. A  element (which can play both audio and video) is changed to the source of the dropped file. This is to preview the file before uploading.

```js
  let reader = new FileReader()

  reader.onload = function (e) {
    video_element.src = e.target.result
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
```

This works SOMETIMES. It works with 1 flac. But if I try with another specific flac I get an error about an invalid URI.

The file plays fine. It plays on my computer and when uploaded. But using the generated URI for that local file preview fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems this only happens on the big > 30mb files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to read huge local video file selected via file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64342837/most-efficient-way-to-read-huge-local-video-file-selected-via-file-input)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that using that method fails with big files like bigger than 30mb.

Instead, you can do this:

```js
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
```